# Discord.js V12: How do I move a category?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've seen multiple posts on how to move a channel but how do I move the actual category itself? I have the category created by the bot, but it creates it all the way at the bottom of the list. How do I move it all the way to the top? And obviously, `.setParent` won't be a fix to the issue:

`My Code:`

```
message.guild.channels.create('Category Name', { type: 'category'});
```

Is there a `.then` statement I could possibly add to move it to the top? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be mistaken to the context, but the property "type" of discord.js's Channels is a constant and has nothing to do with position of the channel, here's [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/GuildChannelCreateOptions).

Notice the "position" parameter - which I assume governs the position of the channel inside of the parent (CategoryChannel). Try passing a number as an additional argument at creation:

```
message.guild.channels.create('Some_Category', { type: 'GUILD_TEXT', position: 1});
```

Comment: Yeah i just saw that, thanks a ton for the help it works :)